# Caliburn Micro Update RowDetails of a Datagrid

Tags: binding, datagrid, refresh, caliburn.micro, rowdetails

Let me explain my problem. I am working with Caliburn Micro and have a datagrid where a ObservableCollection is being binded as an Itemsource:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Models.GamesProperties> _dgGames;

public ObservableCollection<Models.GamesProperties> DgGames
{
    get { return _dgGames; }
    set
    {
        _dgGames = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DgGames);
    }
}
```

So, when I load my data from my database, the collection will be filled and binded to my datagrid (called DgGames)

Everything is fine so far. I have defined for each DataRow "DataRowDetails". Contains an ImageSource, some TextBlocks and so on. The mentioned collection above contains also those DataRowDetails.

I have now created another View and ViewModel for a dialog window in order to change the DataRowDetails. It does work, but the datagrid (DgGames) won't apply these changes. It does not show any update i have done to the collection. What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance to those who can help me.

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see modification on the fly in the grid too, `Models.GamesProperties` has to implemen properly `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Since you are using Caliburn, you probably want to derive it from `PropertyChangedBase`.

Comment: Hm, i already tried to derive it from 'PropertyChangedBase'. Added a 'NotifyOfPropertyChange()' to the object and it did not work properly. The effect was none.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is the right one. It did not work in the first place, because after i have binded the collection to my datagrid, i have used those following two lines which screwed up my `PropertyChangedBase`: `DgGames.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            DgGames.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Name", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));` Hopefully it is readable. Havent been accustomed to the commentbox. Thanks for the hint @FelicePollano